# How to find such $f(n)$, that satisfies $f(n) \equiv x_n \pmod{ 12}$, where $x_n$ is 12-periodic sequence?

Tags: number-theory

How to find such $f(n) \in \mathbb{N}, n \in \mathbb{N}$, that satisfies $f(n) \equiv g(n) \pmod{ 12}, g(n) \in \mathbb{N}$, where $g(n)$ is 12-periodic sequence?
For example $n^m,n \in \mathbb{N}, m=2k+1, k \in \mathbb{N}$ is 12-peridic in terms of $\pmod{12}$( $n^3 \equiv x_n \pmod{12}, \{x_n\}_{n=1}^{12} =[1,8,3,4,5,0,7,8,9,4,11,0]$. Can you find another one that is such that has not all numbers same as in example sequence?

The sequence $(x_n)$ is not given, but it has requirement of being 12-periodic and I'm looking for some other functions than $n^m,n \in \mathbb{N}, m=2k+1, k \in \mathbb{N}$ that generates 12-periodic sequence modulo 12 which has not all numbers same as in example sequence?.

Comment: As $\phi(12)=\phi(3)\phi(4)=4,$ the exponent of $x$ has to be co-prime to $4,$ i.e., odd

Comment: @lad bhattacharjee. I edited question.

Comment: I thought you were trying to form a complete residue $\pmod{12},$ though my idea was not right as $12$ does not have  a primitive root. Now I'm really confused about your requirement

Comment: I didn't understand the question. Is the sequence $(x_n)$ given, and you are asking for all the matching functions $f$? Or are you looking for all functions (polynomials?) such that when reduced modulo twelve, the function repeats with period twelve?

Comment: If you are interested in sequences $f(n)$, where $f(n)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients, then it may be of interest to you that the polynomials $g_1(x)=x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$, $g_2(x)=2x(x-1)(x-2)$ and $g_3=6x(x-1)$ all have values divisible by $12$ only. Therefore all the possibilities are among 
$$f(x)=a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0,$$ with $0\le a_3<2$, $0\le a_2<6$, $0\le a_0,a_1<12$.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen. Does $g_1(x)$ generate 12-periodic sequence that has not all numbers same as in my example sequence?

Comment: No! The $g_i(x),i=1,2,3,$ all generate only zeros modulo 12. So if you reduce any polynomial $p(x)$ modulo the ideal generated by $g_i$:s, you get the same sequence. Thus you are left with that set of $2\cdot6\cdot12^2$ polynomials. Many of them probably have periods shorter than twelve. Also, if you allow non-polynomial functions, then there are more options. Well, with non-polynomial functions you can get anything you want :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen. I do not get only zeros, but a sequence that has exactle same numbers than in my example. Maybe I miss something here now.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen. Can you please tell me something about why quote "the $g_i(x),i=1,2,3, all generate only zeros modulo 12"?

Comment: For all integers $x$ we have that $x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$ is divisible by 24, $x(x-1)(x-2)$ is divisible by 6, and $x(x-1)$ is always even. Therefore $g_i(x)$ is always divisible by 12 and hence $\equiv0\pmod{12}$.

Comment: $x(x-1)$ is even but $x(x-1) \noequiv 0 \pmod{12}$, but rather it is as follows $1(1-1) = 0 \equiv 0 \pmod{12}$, $2(2-1) = 2 \equiv 0 \pmod{12}$, $3(3-1) = 6 \equiv 0 \pmod{12}$, $4(4-1) = 0 \equiv 0 \pmod{12}$, etc. and this generates 12-periodic sequence, thus residue is not always 0 modulo 12. Can you clarify why eq. $6x(x-1)$ is divisible by 12 only?

Comment: I am grateful for any example other than $x^m, m=2k+1, k \in \mathbb{N}$ that satisfies the conditions that I presented?

Comment: As $x(x-1)$ is always divisible by two, surely $6x(x-1)$ is always divisible by $6\cdot2=12$.

Comment: What I am suggesting is the following. Take the polynomial $f(x)=x^5$ as an example. Because the values of $g_1(x)=x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$ are divisible by twelve, we can, instead of $f(x)$, use its remainder modulo $g_1(x)$, namely
$$r_1(x)=f(x)-(x+6)g_1(x)=25x^3-60x^2+36x.$$
For the same reason we can use
$$r_2(x)=r_1(x)-12 g_2(x)=x^3+12x^2-12x$$
instead of $r_1(x)$. Here we see that we can drop the terms divisible by $12$, and see that $f(x)$ and $x^3$ give rise to the same sequence (as you had observed).

Comment: (cont'd)  What I'm saying is that you can do this same replacement stuff to any polynomial in place of $f(x)$. You eventually get a polynomial of the form
$$r_M(x)=a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0,$$ with $0\le a_3<2,$ $0\le a_2<6$ and $0\le a_0,a_1<12$. This "$M^{th}$" remainder gives the same sequence modulo $12$ as the original polynomial. Therefore you only have this finite set of polynomials to try out.

Comment: For example $f(x)=x^3+5x^2$ gives you the sequence 
$$(6,4,0,0,10,0,0,4,6,0,4,0)$$ modulo 12 (it has a full period) and $f(x)=x^3+x^2+x$ gives the sequence
$$(3,2,3,0,11,6,3,8,3,6,11,0).$$ What exactly do you want from the sequence?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen. I would like to have generated a sequence that is not same in cyclical or "raisedwise~elevational" sense as my $n^m, m=2k+1, k \in \mathbb{N}$ polynomial generates(namely sequence that is not cyclic or transposed variation from the sequence [1,8,3,4,5,0,7,8,9,4,11,0] like [2,9,4,5,6,1,8,9,10,0,1] or [1,8,9,10,0,1,2,9,4,5,6] but has these numbers in seemingly random way). I have only thus far found only such odd polynomials that generate cyclic or transposed or both type of variation of above sequence.

Comment: I now find that those example polynomials produce different kind of sequences which I find surprising, because I did found these altghough I tried.